# Create drag-able panels in Flex like its in netvibes.com

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I want to create a news application for my website.

My question is how should i create drag-able panels/canvas inside another panel/canvas.

What i exactly intend to do can be seen on netvibes.com . The website has different panels of every news group, and this panel could be moved from one place to other, but in a well defined manner. And the other panel take over the place of dragged panel.

Is there any component in flex, which can help me make something like that.

If i was unable to make my question clear, plz let me know, i will try to make it more clear.

Regards
Zeeshan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TileList with drag and drop enabled should be able to accomplish something like that.  Or, use a Spark List with a custom layout that you create.

It might be a bit tricky getting the list elements to drag and drop based on clicking the title, but it should be doable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider a more advanced solution with drap-n-drop with a custom panel based component. The places the panels can move can be implemented with a different custom canvas based component. The advantage would be to move the components into different custom positions and panels can be resized independent of each other.

Adobe has some good tutorials for drag-drop operations.